# Removing a Tautology in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writting a function that will remove tautologies from a fomula,the problem is that is working only for consecutive duplicates.The basic idea is that if in a clause, a literal and its negation are found, it means that the clause will be true, regardless of the value finally assigned to that propositional variable.My appoach is to create a function that will remove this but for a clause and map it to the fomula.Of course I have to remove duplicates at the beginning.

```
module Algorithm where

import System.Random
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List

type Atom = String
type Literal = (Bool,Atom)
type Clause = [Literal]
type Formula = [Clause]
type Model = [(Atom, Bool)]
type Node = (Formula, ([Atom], Model))
removeTautologies :: Formula -> Formula
removeTautologies = map tC.map head.group.sort
  where rt ((vx, x) : (vy, y) : clauses) | x == y = rt rest
                                      | otherwise = (vx, x) : rt ((vy, y) : clauses)
```

Now I have problems because I'm only checking for consecutive literals and I do not know how to change that since I'm new to haskell(not an excuse,I know),so when I try to give it a formula (for example (A v B v -A) ^ (B v C v A)) it just returns the exact input.Considering that example the first clause contains the literals A and -A. This means that the clause will always be true, in which case it can be simplify the whole set to simply (B v C v A) .

What changes should I write for my function so that I can remove a tautology in the right way?
Can I implement sortBy?If yes ,how?map head.group.sortBy snd?

Comment: what if I can sort?but what happens if I write a function that sort but I meet an input that isalready sorted?

Comment: I don't mean to be too rude, but I'm really tired of these questions spamming the haskell tag. Homework help questions are ok in moderation, but this is too much. If you need this much help with this much detail, please take it to the #haskell irc channel on freenode.

Comment: spamming?My intention is to learn...when I'm stuck because of the lack of knowledge I ask for help because I want to understand ...how exactly is a question that you can ignore gets you "tired"?! I'm also tired of others arrogance....if you can't offer any advice please try and ignore the questions.

Comment: You are asking frequent and trivial questions, and then editing them so that any possible train of discussion is lost. You don't use consistent spaces, much less clear grammar. If you want good answers to your questions, please put effort into asking them clearly and well, and only ask things that you've put thought into, not just whatever occurs to you. If you want to have a more rapid style of question and answer, stackoverflow is *not* the place for that, irc is.

Comment: This link might prove useful: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: 7 questions in 13 days,I assume you are not very good at math..also the is a rule on stackoverflow it is called BE NICE..because not all share your knowledge in the field...second I'm not a native which justifies my grammar..third since I'm presenting my work whcih reflects the fact that I've put some thought in it....and fourth your are starting to exagerate and take things to personal I do not know what your problem is and I don't care so please stop posting as I said my intention is to learn and I only have 2 weeks since I started haskell so my "trivial" question are not so trivial to me...

Comment: 7 in just over 10 days, and 4 in the last 24 hours. There is a rule 'be nice'. Not speaking English as your native tongue should not count against you, but no-one commenting on this question has said that your use of English is a problem. If you resolve a question on your own, it is best to add the answer to the question, leaving the question substantially unchanged (you can always make editorial corrections - fix typos, etc). If anyone has answered or commented on your question, it is best to leave the bulk of the question intact, even if you modify the question. You might use <s>...</s>.

Comment: I agree...but can you observe how this topic from its sole purpose of increasing comprenhension in a field is converging towards a debate of frustrations...I'm sure there are other bigger probems like poverty,taxes,education etc...that we all are "tired" of

Comment: Hi, TKFALS.  When engaging a new online community for the first time, it is customary to read the rules and familiarize yourself with the way things work.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/faq, and read a few posted questions and answers to get a feel for what is considered on-topic here.  Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Make a [structure of your choice] of the elements

1. If the element is inside the structure, remove it from the list.
2. Elseway, pass it both to the outout list and add it to your structure.

This is basically the same as `nubBy`, find out how to implement it!

Comment: @FUZxxl...I know about nub...nubBy is similar to nub, but it allows my own equality test apparently ....but I dont' see how this will work since I have to remove a clause ,which is made of elements, from a formula not an element itself

Comment: Have a look at the source-code for `nub`: http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/src/Data-List.html#nub Try to implement something similiar for your own case.

Comment: @FuZxxl...the source code give me an ideea...what if I can write       rt ((vx, x) : clauses) | x `elem clausse && neg x elem clausses = rt rest
                                      | otherwise = (vx, x) : rt (( clauses)

Comment: if I want to sort by literals using sortBy what should I write map head.group.sortBy snd?